# List index does not recognize class object; results attribute error

Tags: python, function, class, object, attributes

So I'm trying to make a role-playing generator where you can create your own creature, add the attributes, and store it in a list.

Here is the code:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.feet = None
        self.inches = None
        self.weight = None
        self.gender = None

    def getName(self):
        return "Name: {}".format(self.name)

    def setName(self, name):
         self.name = name

    def getHeight(self):
        return "Height: {} ft. {} in.".format(self.feet, self.inches)

    def setFeet(self, feet):
        self.feet = feet

    def setInches(self, inches):
        self.inches = inches

    def getWeight(self):
        return "Weight: {} lbs.".format(self.weight)

    def setWeight(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def getGender(self):
        return "Gender: {}".format(self.gender)

    def setGender(self, index):
        genders = ['Male', 'Female', 'Others']
        if int(index) == 1:
            self.gender = genders[0]
        elif int(index) == 2:
            self.gender = genders[1]
        elif int(index) == 3:
            self.gender = genders[2]

class Dragon(Creature):
    pass

class Mermaid(Creature):
    pass

class Fairy(Creature):
    pass

class Vampire(Creature):
    pass


#allows the user to change attributes of creature
def changeAttributes(creature):
    value = input("Pick an attribute to change: 1) name   2) height   3) weight   4) gender   5) save")
    if int(value) == 1:
        creature.setName(input("Enter a name: "))
        changeAttributes(creature)
    elif int(value) == 2:
        creature.setFeet(input("Enter a foot value: "))
        creature.setInches(input("Enter an inch value: "))
        changeAttributes(creature)
    elif int(value) == 3:
        creature.setWeight(input("Enter a value in pounds: "))
        changeAttributes(creature)
    elif int(value) == 4:
        creature.setGender(input("Enter a value to set gender; 1 = male, 2 = female, 3 = others: "))
        changeAttributes(creature)
    elif int(value) == 5:
        confirm = input("Save?  1) yes  2) no")
        if int(confirm) == 1:
            print('Saving...')
            creature = creature.getName()
            menu(creature)
        else:
            changeAttributes(creature)
    else:
        print("Not a valid input, please try again.")
        changeAttributes(creature)

#prints the attributes of the creature
def showAttributes(creature):
    print(creature.getName())
    print(creature.getHeight())
    print(creature.getWeight())
    print(creature.getGender())

def Delete(creature):
    a = input("Are you sure?  1) yes   2) no  ")
    if int(a) == 1:
        print("Deleting...")
        creature = None
        main()
    elif int(a) == 2:
        print("Cancelled")
        menu(creature)

#checks to see if slot is empty or has a creature object; if empty, create a creature, otherwise go to creature menu
def menu(creature):
    value = input("Select an option  1) Show Attributes   2) Change Attributes  3) Delete   4) Back")
    if int(value) == 1:
        showAttributes(creature)
        menu(creature)
    elif int(value) == 2:
        changeAttributes(creature)
        menu(creature)
    elif int(value) == 3:
        Delete(creature)
    elif int(value) == 4:
        main()

#checks if slot is empty, if empty, choose a creature subclass and change attributes, else takes user directly to change attribute menu
def check(slot):
    if slot == None:
        a = input('Choose a creature: 1) Dragon   2) Fairy   3) Mermaid   4) Vampire')
        if int(a) == 1:
            slot = Dragon()
        elif int(a) == 2:
            slot = Fairy()
        elif int(a) == 3:
            slot = Mermaid()
        elif int(a) == 4:
            slot = Vampire()
        return changeAttributes(slot)
        #party[0] = slot
    else:
        menu(slot)


a = None
b = None
c = None
d = None
e = None

party = [a, b, c, d, e]

#user select a slot; note that since development has not finished, you can only change slot 1
def main():
    print(party)
    inp = input("Select a slot: ")
    if int(inp) == 1:
        print("Slot 1 selected!")
        check(party[0])
    elif int(inp) == 2:
        print("Slot 2 selected!")
        check(party[1])
    elif int(inp) == 3:
        print("Slot 3 selected!")
        check(party[2])
    elif int(inp) == 4:
        print("Slot 4 selected!")
        check(party[3])
    elif int(inp) == 5:
        print("Slot 5 selected!")
        check(party[4])

main()
```

However, when I tried to use the showAttribute() function to return and display the attributes of a creature from a selected slot, it results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 160, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 146, in main
    check(party[0])
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 126, in check
    return changeAttributes(slot)
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 60, in changeAttributes
    changeAttributes(creature)
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 76, in changeAttributes
    menu(creature)
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 104, in menu
    showAttributes(creature)
  File "C:\Users\sarim\PycharmProjects\RolePlayingBuilder\main.py", line 85, in showAttributes
    print(creature.getName())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getName'
```

I think the issue is that while running the program, when returning back to the main system after setting up the attributes for the first time, the list does not recognize the class object and remains with a None value. I was wondering how I could get it so that a user-input slot from the party list changes from None to the class object. I managed to temporarily fixed the issue by putting a party[0] = slot in the check() function. However, this only changes the first index of the party; the other slots cannot be modified. Any way to fix that?

Edit: A comment has told me to remove the line creature = creature.getName() after print("Saving..."). I did that and the error went away and I could view the attributes immediately after setting them. However, when I return back to main(), the party slot still has a None value instead of the class attribute; I want it to stay until delete(Creature) is called.

Comment: How did you get this error? What is the step in between? Can you show me the previous few input before the error?

Comment: Here's how the code is supposed to work. As long as main() is running, first, the user input an integer (1-5) as the screen displays the party list. Whichever the input is 1-5, it will select the corresponding index, and it checks if the slot index is None or has a class object stored. If None, it makes you choose which creature you want and change its attributes.

Comment: After that, it takes you to the object menu. Otherwise, it will straight-up take you there to the object menu. The problem is, after setting up the attributes and returning back to the menu, the program does not recognize the class object in the list, resulting in an attribute error if you select showAttributes().

Comment: Try remove  `creature = creature.getName()` after the `print('Saving...')`

Comment: Did that, it finally removed the error and I can show the attribute right after setting them. However, when I go back to main(), the party slot still resets to a None value.

Comment: Of course it is `None`, you haven't assign the object to the party like `party[0] = slot`. But that's another problem you need to figure out.

Comment: Ok, but why do I need to set the value party index variable? Doesn't it already work with the parameters themselves?